# txt header R recognize it as only one variable

Tags: r

[image]

I try to open a "file.txt" with this header with `read.table("/home/.../data.txt, header=TRUE, sep=",")` but R recognize that there is only one variable. How can I change the header and not doing manually by changing mirna ID with mirna_ID? thank you very much

Comment: when I do str() its appear as 9994 obs. and 1 variable. The variable is like miR.family.Seed.m8 etc, R is not able to recognize the variables miR family Seed+m8 etc

Comment: That looks tab separated, not comma separated. You could try `read.delim("/home/.../data.txt")` and see if that works.

Comment: yes!! indeed I use read.delim and works perfectly id did not know that option to open txt files!! thanks a lot!!!